# Suspending system using c++ program

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to suspend my system using a c++ program using **SetSuspendState** method but I am facing issue during linking.

I am using **g++-4 (GCC) 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1** compiler on Windows 7 OS (64bit).

The code I have written is

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "powrprof.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << SetSuspendState(false, true, false);
    return 0;
}
```

Following is the error I am facing:

> /cygdrive/c/Users/Vikas/AppData/Local/Temp/ccFpLgPi.o:suspend.cpp:(.text+0xa4):
>   undefined reference to
>   `_SetSuspendState@12' collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

Kindly help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: It's full of errors (`<iostream>`, `using`, `namespace`, `std`, `cout`)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373201%28VS.85%29.aspx) says you need to link PowrProf.lib.

Comment: I guess it is bundled only along with VC++. I tried to search powerprof.lib it for download but was unsuccessful.

Comment: On MinGW, it should be something like libpowerprof.a. That's why I prefer to compile with VC++ on Windows and g++ on Linux, there are much less problems with documentation using "standard" compilers and SDKs.

Answer (score 3):

I believe [`dlltool`](http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/dlltool) can be used to create import libraries from DLLs for use with GCC under Cygwin. The DLL exporting the functions `pwrprof.dll` should be located in your Windows system directory somewhere.